# Деструктурирующее присваивание и словари в Python

Tags: python

В Javascript есть [деструктурирующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Вопрос: как реализовать подобное на Python. Хотелось бы иметь вот такой синтаксис, но т.к. это не возможно, может модуль какой есть?

```
{
    "foo": {
        "spam": fooSpam, 
        "eggs": fooEggs
    }, 
    "bar": {
        "spam": barSpam, 
        "eggs": barEggs
   }
} = {"foo": {
           "spam: 1, 
           "eggs": 2
     }, 
     "bar": {
           "spam": 3, 
           "eggs": 4
     }
}
print(fooSpam) # 1
# ...
```

### Update

На скорую руку набросал нечто такое:

```
def destruct(arr, pattern):
    result = {}
    for k in pattern:
        item = arr.get(k)
        if item is None:
            if isinstance(pattern[k], dict):
                result.update(destruct([], pattern[k]))
                continue
            result[pattern[k]] = None
            continue
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            result.update(destruct(item, pattern[k]))
        else:
            result[pattern[k]] = item
    return result 

# Использование
print( destruct({"a": {"a1": 34, "a2": "Foo"}, "b": True},
                {"a": {"a1": "var1", "a2": "var2", "a404": "var3"}, "b": "boolVar"})) 
# Prints {'var1': 34, 'var2': 'Foo', 'var3': None, 'boolVar': True}
```

<s>Но вопрос все еще открыт: есть ли "штатный" способ?</s>
**Будем считать вопрос решенным**

Comment: ну а если вы создадите два таких словарика, что должен показать fooSpam ?

Comment: В данном примере: fooSpam, fooEggs, barSpam и barEggs равны соответсвенно 1, 2, 3 и 4

Comment: мне кажется, то что вы сделали, к деструкутурирующему присваиванию никакого отнишения не имеет. И штатного способа нет

Comment: А я и не говорил, что это деструкутурирующее присваивание в чистом виде. В данном случае: это просто функция, обрабатывающая словарь по определенному алгоритму. Просто она чем-то результатом работы напоминает такое присваивание. А что "штатного" способа нет так это не беда.

Answer (score 2):

На счет специальных модулей не знаю, а вот что первое пришло в голову (для python 3):

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a, b, c, *rest = arr
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>> rest
[4, 5]
```

Для присваивания кортежу из словаря:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 5}
>>> a, b, c, *rest = list(map(lambda x: x[1], sorted(d.items())))
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>> rest
[4, 5]
```